# Any software to stub mails from a firmware with no smtp password capability?

Tags: ups, email-server

We have a MGE U.P.S. (Evolution S 3000) with the ability to send mails when power down occurs. The thing is that the firmware settings doesn't allow to send using smtp accounts requiring password and our system requires it.

Anyone knows about any mail-server-tool which allows to do something like this:

1. A client (the UPS firmware) connects to this mail-server-tool to send mail without password.
2. The mail-server-tool sends again the mail through our servers providing smtp passwords.

I know it's a very strange behavior but the MPE service says that there is no upgrade to firmware and no way to solve it...

I hope I explained the issue nicely!!

**Update 1**: The main problem on this is that there is no access to SMTP server, then it s not possible to change the server configuration in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Two options,

1. Can you configure your SMTP server to accept by IP address and verify that way?
2. Setup another SMTP server that does not require the password and have it forward using it's smarthost option to your primary mail server, or just direct send it.  Using hMailServer is one of those options

I like #1 better if you can do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

What your effectively after is a mail relay, which you can do with most email servers. You setup the relay to accept mail without authentication, then configure it to forward on mail to a smarthost, in this case your real mail server, with the correct credentials.

By doing this however, your new relay, becomes an open relay, and is open to spam use if its open to the outside world, so you may have to lock it down to only accept email from certain IP's. If your doing this, then you may want to instead look at getting your real mail server to accept mail without authentication from certain IP's. You can do this with Exchange and I'm sure many other mail servers will do this.

Now if you don't have access to the mailserver then that's not an option, and the additional relay is probably needed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll essentially need to setup a proxy.

Configure a lightweight mail server somewhere (preferably with its own local UPS if this is an important UPS that it's monitoring) that accepts mail only from the MGE (possibly via a direct ethernet cable) and then forwards it on to the real mail server.